# How to use React with ASP.NET Web Form

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reactjs

I wanted to try out React in our existing WebForm application and below is the approach i followed

Aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<script src="../Scripts/react/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jsx/SplitRate.jsx"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="OneColumnContent" 
runat="server">

<h1 id="hello"></h1>

</asp:Content>
```

JSX

```
var SplitRate = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(
  <SplitRate name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('hello')
);
```

Here I'm having trouble loading the h1 tag and I'm getting a blank page.Please help.

Comment: It doesn't sound feasible.  ASP.NET has its own way of doing things; it will be constantly fighting you and React.

Comment: Are there any errors in the javascript console? If so, please add them to the question.

Comment: The issue is that `.jsx` files require a build step.  They are not natively supported by browsers.  The only real way I know around this for React is to instead use `React.createElement`.  See [react without jsx](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html).

Comment: Sure, create a separate built version of your react application, and render to that one, but as mentioned, jsx would probably only work if you are including babel transformations as well (a bit like in the snippets here)

Comment: Yup, gotta transpile that jsx to something browsers will understand, or use react without jsx

Comment: I did see this [article](https://medium.com/@vardalis/integrating-react-in-a-visual-studio-web-application-5a01a77406f8). Maybe this works?